# Why does my Generic MP3 Player with Video Support won't load videos and says empty disk?

Tags: video, usb, mp3

Recently I bought a Generic MP3 Player from Amazon ([http://www.amazon.com/Generic-Screen-Media-Video-Players/dp/B00EZOK8B8/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1441656806&sr=8-1&keywords=generic+ipod&pebp=1441656809917&perid=0RA8EP89497J1JD8077H](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EZOK8B8)) and it says it supports videos. I have tried WMV and ASF formats and it won't load those videos. On top of that it is very difficult to get my computer (running Xubuntu) to recognize the drive (it turns the device on, just won't connect to drive). I have tried multiple cables so it is not the cable. Beyond that, I want to be able to watch videos on this Generic MP3 (it even has a menu that says videos) and when I load the videos menu it shows empty disk. The MP3 music works fine, the videos won't show up on the device (when connected with USB it shows the files). This is very frustrating. I can't get USB to work without extreme effort and ask putting the files on it won't let me play the video. I tried 2 of the supported video formats (WMV and ASF). What can I do to fix this? (First one wouldn't turn on so got a warranty replacement) Any advice would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

did u try to turn it off and on?

Comment: Yes, that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [description](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EZOK8B8)  Generic Player supports only AMV video format.

> Support multiple audio music formats: .MP3.WMA.WAV.etc. Support AMV video format, AVI are convertible To AMV. format

Essentially it supports WMA audio in ASF file format. It does not support video in ASF file format. This includes WMV as well. From what I can find [AMV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMV_video_format) is a proprietary variant of an AVI file format.  So if you can find a way to convert your videos to AMV format, then the device may recognize the video files. You can have a look at [tutorial](https://moralvolcano.wordpress.com/2014/03/02/how-to-convert-any-video-file-to-amv-using-ffmpeg/) on creating AMV files using FFMPEG.

Comment: Oh AMV, i though it said ASF let me try that

Answer (score 0):

Me, I just insert SD card into my computer and then allow it to get all the files on there, and then just pop it back in.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).